# re expand a partitioned disk

Tags: disk-utility, partition, disk-space, core-storage

The internal disk of my Mac book pro is partitioned as follows:

```
% diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS mainHD                  249.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:          Apple_CoreStorage                         249.1 GB   disk0s4
   5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s5
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS oldHD                  *248.7 GB   disk1


% diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group C2BDDBCA-73CF-473C-B9DA-E5682EF29610
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD 2
    Status:       Online
    Size:         249059012608 B (249.1 GB)
    Free Space:   35708928 B (35.7 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume CA1B7050-0A3D-4FFD-ADC2-AE42B45BEB9C
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s4
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     249059012608 B (249.1 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 4CBD3D40-147F-4B2D-A997-975E00295101
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   No
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume B3E1FCD6-ACAB-4152-AEB5-71F41C329C17
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          248687755264 B (248.7 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   -none-
            Revertible:            Yes (no decryption required)
            LV Name:               oldHD
            Volume Name:           oldHD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

The operating system (os x 10.9.5) and all my files are in the `mainHD`, where I'm running out of space. I would like to delete the `oldHD` so that I can increase the size of `mainHD`.

When I try to delete `oldHD` via the graphical disk utility I get an `Alert (null)` box where I can select `cancel` or `remove`, if I click on `remove` nothing happens and in the log I see:

```
: Preparing to remove partition from disk: “APPLE SSD SM512E Media”
: Could not unmount partition to be deleted.
```

How can I get `oldHD` deleted and `mainHD` resized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete CoreStorage volumes you have to use the CLI:

- please backup your volume "mainHD"
- boot to Internet Recovery Mode (hit <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> immediately after the start-up chime)
- open Disk Utility and check/repair mainHD
- quit Disk Utility , open in the menubar Utilities/Terminal.app and enter `diskutil cs deleteVolume LVUUID` to delete the Logical Volume
  in your case: `diskutil cs deleteVolume B3E1FCD6-ACAB-4152-AEB5-71F41C329C17`
- and then
  `diskutil cs delete LVGUUID` to delete the Logical Volume Group
  in your case: `diskutil cs delete C2BDDBCA-73CF-473C-B9DA-E5682EF29610`. Your LGV will be converted to a simple, empty volume with the name "Untitled".
- enter `diskutil list` and `sudo gpt -r -vvv show -l /dev/disk0`
  result of the latter (start blocks and block sizes differ because the example disk is half as big as yours & some parts of the output are omitted):

  ```
  ...
           40       409600      1  GPT part - "EFI System Partition"
       409640    244763224      2  GPT part - "mainHD"
    245172864      1269536      3  GPT part - "Recovery HD"
    246442400    242522776      4  GPT part - "Untitled"
    488965176      1269536      5  GPT part - "Recovery HD"
  ...
  ```
- enter `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0`
- then remove any partition except those with index 1 and 2 (EFI and mainHD) with  `sudo gpt remove -i IndexNumber disk0`
- enter `diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 0b` to expand it to the full size.
- enter `exit` and quit Terminal
- open Disk Utility, check/repair mainHD again and quit afterwards
- reboot to main HD
- rebuild Recovery HD with [Recovery Partition Creator 3.8](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13872235/Musings/Recovery%20Partition%20Creator%203.8.zip) or by just reinstalling Mavericks 10.9.5 (don't use 10.9.4 or earlier!). Your data and apps will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I did the deletion with the command line, and the resizing with the graphic utility.

Comment: @user72464 ok and what did you do with your second Recovery HD?

Comment: it's not there any more, it must be gone when I deleted the Logical volume